# Best practice: How to name i18n translation strings

Tags: python, django, gettext, django-i18n

I am building a multilingual site using `django`. I am wondering what is the best practice for naming the strings in `gettext` functions.

I see the following possibilities:

1. Use English words and Translator comments

   ```
   # Translators: This is the login button text
   login = ugettext('Login')
   ```

   Here I see the problem, that I will end up using [`pgettext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/translation/#contextual-markers) most of the time to specify the context.
2. Use some kind of unique identifier and Translator comments

   ```
   # Translators: This is the login button text
   login = ugettext('login_view_buttontext')
   ```

   Is there some kind of naming convention? This one has the obvious downside during development.

Comment: why dont you use the english variant of the word ?